# PDO inserting the same data twice

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I have got this Jquery Ajax code

```
$("body").on('keyup', '.add_thing_t', function(event) {
    if(event.which==13){
        var v=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: "add_thing="+v,
            success:function(a){
                // alert(a);
            }
        })  
    }
});
```

And this PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['add_thing'])) {
    $Val=$_GET['add_thing'];
    $query=$dbh->query("INSERT INTO Ttd (`Thing`) VALUES('$Val')");
    $query->execute();  
}
```

This code is working,but it always inserts the same data twice.

Comment: because u are pressing the button twice

Comment: No i click once @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: `->query` executes it one time, `->execute` does it a second time. I only say this because I cannot see how your system is setup or what class you're using for your database interactions

Comment: @JayBlanchard yep thanks,that was the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->query` executes it one time, `->execute` does it a second time. You need to remove the `execute`.